# Can I prevent certain child processes from getting logged in process accounting

Tags: process

I just rolled out a fairly awesome set of thousands of scripts that I want to run fairly constantly, everything is great with them, except they wind up in the process accounting log and are filling up my hard drive to a greater extend than I'd like.

Is there an exclude list for process accounting (or a way root can run scripts that isn't accounted for?)

I'm running SlES 12 SP4 fwiw

Comment: Do you need `acct(2)` or would maybe something custom via SystemTap or the like be able to record what you need to record?

Comment: @thrig that's global, I want process accounting for everything except the commands I'm running as a via subprocess in a python script that I've got running as a service. I had almost 2000 scripts that I was running every 15 seconds.  I've pared it down to running 1200 scripts every 2 minutes instead and it's considerably more manageable, not as CPU intensive either.

Comment: `acct` is just as global and rather less flexible